# why does the height of my widget not fill completely the div?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, height

Here is my iframe :

```html
<div class="col-md-5 md-offset-1 col-sm-12" >
  <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://app.mailjet.com/widget/iframe/2lW2/4ew" width="100%" height="224"></iframe>     
</div>
```

And here is the result :

[image]

As you can see :

1. there is a scrollbar, although i specified "no".
2. I need to scoll to access the confirmation button

When I increase the height of iFrame, it doesn't resize the inside box.

Any help ?

Comment: You can use Repsonsive embed - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#responsive-embed and remove col-md-* classes.

Comment: The `scrolling` attribute in an `iframe` is deprecated and not supported in HTML5. But apart from that, the content that you are referencing inside the iframe has a maximum height, taller than which it cannot display.